# elemIndex in conjunction with splitAt Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm pretty new to Haskell and can't figure out how to solve the following problem that I have.

I have to implement the following function "ca" which takes a list and an element and deletes all of the other elements in the list after the input element:

```
ca:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

I'm not allowed to change any of the function types and have so far come up with the following code:

```
ca x xs = let (ys, zs) = splitAt (elemIndex x xs) xs in ys
```

This produces the following error:

```
couldn't match expected type 'Int' with the actual type 'Maybe Int'
```

Now I understand why this error is occurring however I do not understand how I can fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using indexes, you can use the [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v%3abreak) function, which splits a list just before the position where a predicate first becomes `True`.

```
> break (== 'x') "aabaaccxaabbcc"
("aabaacc","xaabbcc")
```

Or, since you're discarding the second part anyway, you can use [`takeWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v%3atakeWhile).

```
> takeWhile (/= 'x') "aabaaccxaabbcc"
"aabaacc"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should typecheck, although the function is unsafe now:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

ca x xs = let (ys, zs) = splitAt (fromJust $ elemIndex x xs) xs in ys
```

The reason is `elemIndex` type is `elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`  and you want to extract the `Int` out of the `Maybe` and pass it to the `splitAt` function. This is what `fromJust` function does. `fromJust` will extract out the value from `Just` datatype.

You can try writing the safe alternative of this function using `maybe` or any other alternative function.

Comment: Thanks Sibi my code works now however could you explain to me what  the $ symbol is used for?

Comment: @RyanGibson `$` is used for avoiding parenthesis. `(fromJust $ elemIndex x xs)` and `(fromJust (elemIndex x xs))` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
let 
  Just n = elemIndex x xs
  (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs
in ys
```

However, if the specified element isn't present, this will throw an exception due to a "pattern match failure". A better way is this:

```
case elemIndex x xs of
  Just n  -> let (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs in ys
  Nothing -> {- decide what to do if there's no match! -}
```

However, I concur with Hammar. You're not really trying to split the list into two parts; you're only interested in *one* of those parts. So rather than hunt through the list, find the element you want, return its index, and then hunt through the list a second time, why not just use `break` or `takeWhile`?